# adb Key event for Keyboard next key

Tags: android, adb

I have the login page as shown in the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJSy.png). This is the native app login page.
[image]

When I try to log in, my keyboard hides the password textbox/ sign in button, so I need to click on the next key which I have marked with black circle.

I want to automate the clicking of the button.

Can anybody precisely tell me what is the key event for this key? Also I need ADB command to send this key event to the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`adb shell input keyevent <keycode>`**

For the next key event, [TAB](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_TAB) is used

```
adb shell input keyevent 61
```

Some of the events that can be passed (For more, refer to this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent))

```
0
KEYCODE_UNKNOWN
1
KEYCODE_MENU
2
KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT
3
KEYCODE_HOME
4
KEYCODE_BACK
5
KEYCODE_CALL
6
KEYCODE_ENDCALL
7
KEYCODE_0
8
KEYCODE_1
9
KEYCODE_2
10
KEYCODE_3
11
KEYCODE_4
12
KEYCODE_5
13
KEYCODE_6
14
KEYCODE_7
15
KEYCODE_8
16
KEYCODE_9
17
KEYCODE_STAR
18
KEYCODE_POUND
19
KEYCODE_DPAD_UP
20
KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
21
KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT
22
KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT
23
KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER
24
KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
25
KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
26
KEYCODE_POWER
27
KEYCODE_CAMERA
28
KEYCODE_CLEAR
29
KEYCODE_A
30
KEYCODE_B
31
KEYCODE_C
32
KEYCODE_D
33
KEYCODE_E
34
KEYCODE_F
35
KEYCODE_G
36
KEYCODE_H
37
KEYCODE_I
38
KEYCODE_J
39
KEYCODE_K
40
KEYCODE_L
41
KEYCODE_M
42
KEYCODE_N
43
KEYCODE_O
44
KEYCODE_P
45
KEYCODE_Q
46
KEYCODE_R
47
KEYCODE_S
48
KEYCODE_T
49
KEYCODE_U
50
KEYCODE_V
51
KEYCODE_W
52
KEYCODE_X
53
KEYCODE_Y
54
KEYCODE_Z
55
KEYCODE_COMMA
56
KEYCODE_PERIOD
```

Comment: Thanks @Sahil Manchanda

Answer (score 1):

Since the existing and accepted answer is not clear, the `Next` button corresponds to the TAB keycode, so keyevent 61

```
adb shell input keyevent 61
```